# C# Accessing ListViewItem from BGW

Tags: c#, listview, backgroundworker

I'm writing a program that handles DBs and writes any changes into ListView for user to proccess them. After that It is suposed to write all changes back into DB but I can't figure out how to reach ListView.ListViewItemCollection from BGW. I've tried to use Control.Invoke but I'm affraid I'm not yet skilled enough to make it work.

The error I'm getting says I can't access that control from thread that it was not created on

```
 private delegate void BGOUdate(ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic);
 BGOU = new BGOUdate(ApplyChanges);
 bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(lvProducts.Items);

 private void bgwSearcher_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {          
        BGOU(e.Argument as ListView.ListViewItemCollection);                
    }

 private void ApplyChanges(ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic)
    {
        ...
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvic)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Post some actual *code* so that we can exactly see what you are having problems with. Moreover, what about the platform - is this WPF, Silverlight, WinForms, ASP.NET,... ?

Comment: It's a simple Windows Forms app

Comment: What is an exact error you are getting? Try to post the simplest possible code that would enable us to duplicate your error. Preferrably, omit classes that are internal to your application (like `CSVBuilder` or `CategoryExt`) - they make it difficult to duplicate the error on machine other than yours. Don't mean to sound harsh here, just trying to provide some helpful hints so that people can actually answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Control.Invoke` is the right way to walk. But you need to pass the control to the background worker, not just its `ItemCollection`:

```
private void ApplyChanges(ListView lv) 
{ 
    lv.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items) 
        { 
            ... 
        }
    }); 
    ... 
}
```

This way, all changes to the ListViewItems will be made in the thread that created the controls.

`Action` is a predefined void delegate that takes no arguments. The keyword `delegate` marks the following block as an anonymous function and returns a delegate to this, which is then cast to an `Action` that can be invoked on the control. The call to `Invoke` causes the passed delegate to be executed on the thread that is associated with the control's window handle, which is almost everytime the creator thread.

Maybe, you should consider DataBinding as an option to keep GUI elements in sync with your data.

Comment: Could you provide more information on Invoke? What you mean by (Action)

Comment: Done. The `(Action)` specifies a cast of the delegate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and tell whether or not it's working how it's suposed to.